# "No information about coverage per test." from Sonar with Jacoco Ant build

Tags: java, ant, junit, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm using Ant, Jacoco and Sonar. When I run my build Sonar tells me that "No information about coverage per test." and the Sonar dashboard has my coverage results, but I cannot drill down into them to see the code. However, the HTML report generated by Jacoco does include drill down into the code. This is my coverage task:

```
    <jacoco:coverage destfile="${coverage.output.file}" >
        <junit printsummary="on" 
            errorProperty="test.failed" 
            failureProperty="test.failed" 
            haltonfailure="yes" 
            fork="true">
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <classpath>
                <path refid="test.build.class.path"/>
                <pathelement location="${test.bin.dir}"/>       
            </classpath>
            <batchtest todir="${results.dir}">
                <fileset dir="${test.bin.dir}">
                    <include name = "**/**/*Test.class"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </jacoco:coverage>  

    <jacoco:report>
        <executiondata>
            <file file="${coverage.output.file}"/>
        </executiondata>
        <structure name="${ant.project.name}">
            <classfiles>
                <fileset dir="${bin.dir}"/>
            </classfiles>
            <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                <fileset dir="${src.dir}"/>
            </sourcefiles>
        </structure>
        <html destdir="${coverage.results.dir}"/>
    </jacoco:report>
</target>
```

And my Sonar target looks like this:

```
<target name="sonar" depends = "run">
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="..." />
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="...r" />
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="..." />

    <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="org.codehaus.sonar:example-java-ant" />
    <property name="sonar.projectName" value="${ant.project.name} (ant)" />
    <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />
    <property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
    <property name="sonar.sources" value="${src.dir}" />
    <property name="sonar.binaries" value="${bin.dir},${test.bin.dir}" />
    <property name="sonar.libraries" value="${lib.dir}/*.jar" />    

    <property name="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="reuseReports" />
    <property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="${results.dir}" />
    <property name="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
    <property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="${coverage.output.file}" />

    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
         <classpath>         
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="sonar-ant-task-2.0.jar"/>
         </classpath>
    </taskdef>   

    <sonar:sonar />     
</target>
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't set the 'sonar.tests' property to tell Sonar where to find the source code of your unit tests. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters.

David RACODON | SonarSource

Comment: I confirm - in my case, this was set to test sources, whereas it should point to the compiled classes.

Comment: I've tried adding the sonar.tests property to point to both source code and byte code. Neither worked. I'm still stumped with this.

Comment: I have the same problem. I think this may be a bug with the Ant task as I had done this using Sonar Runner and it worked fine, but the same properties in Ant fail.

Comment: Happens with gradle builds as well.

Comment: Haven't you try adding this property: sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=target/jacoco-it.exec ?

Comment: @AdamAdamaszek, you are wrong. As stated clearly in the Analysis Parameters section  at the link above, the `sonar.tests` property should contain comma-separated paths to directories containing test **source** files.

Answer (score 1):

The `sonar.test` property should be set to the test-classes.  We have the following in our maven pom.  For ANT you do something similar:

```
    <profile>
        <id>sonarprofile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.host.url>....our host..../sonar.host.url>
            <sonar.projectKey>....our key....</sonar.projectKey>
            <sonar.projectName>${project.artifactId}</sonar.projectName>
            <sonar.projectVersion>${project.version}</sonar.projectVersion>
            <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
            <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
            <!-- sonar.tests>target/test-classes</sonar.tests -->
            <!-- that is the default location for Maven projects and -->
            <!-- this parameter can't actually be set in that case -->
            <sonar.scm.provider>git</sonar.scm.provider>
            <sonar.login>${SONAR_LOGIN}</sonar.login>
            <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
            <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
            <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Incidently there are some other properties being used in this:

- I've generated a SONAR token through my sonar user rather than use login and password
- JaCoCo coverage is being generated separately using the `jacoco-maven-plugin` and the `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` is a property used in that plugin.

David Racodon's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16645108/1019307) was once correct but in mid-2014 SonarQube stopped executing the tests as part of the sonar execution (http://www.sonarqube.org/unit-test-execution-in-sonarqube/).  Hence why pointing to the test source no longer works.

Comment: It's `sonar.tests`, not `sonar.test` Also: "Not compatible with Maven, which retrieves test from the default location for Java Maven projects." See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters

Comment: Ok that is one parameter wrong (although it did work for me).  Although it isn't actually wrong but redundant. Is that a reason to downvote?  A simple comment would have had me update my answer.