# Sonar does not pick up test coverage information

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

Similar to [SonarQube does not display detailed report per file for fully covered classes via Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23875038/327426) but not a dupe.

Sonar Qube version 3.7.4
Gradle version 2.1

Running the `gradle sonarRunner` generates a file test.exec which Sonar **does** pick up

```
14:50:28.167 INFO  - Analysing D:\projname\build\jacoco\test.exec
14:50:28.265 INFO  - No information about coverage per test.
14:50:28.266 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 106 ms
14:50:28.529 INFO  - Execute decorators...
14:50:29.253 INFO  - Store results in database
14:50:29.391 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/com.projname
```

However on refreshing the said project it shows coverage at 0%

Unit Tests Coverage
0.0%
0.0% line coverage
0.0% branch coverage

I have set

```groovy
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath', 'D:\\projname\\build\\jacoco\\test.exec'
        property 'sonar.junit.reportsPath','$buildDir/test-results'
        property 'sonar.tests', "$buildDir/classes/test"
     }
}
```

I have tried \ and forward slashes - it does not make a difference

any ideas?

**EDIT**

As per Peter's answer, removed the `sonarProperties` - so build.gradle basically is

```groovy
subprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'eclipse'
   apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'
   apply plugin: 'jacoco'
   sourceCompatibility  = 1.7
   group = 'com.mycomp'
   version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    }
}
```

This does not read the default exec file which is generated at D:\projname\build\jacoco\test.exec

Instead it gives the message

```
17:06:36.912 INFO  - Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: D:\projname\target\jacoco.exec
```

Question: Does spaces in folder names cause a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gradle test sonarRunner` to make sure that test and coverage results are up-to-date. Avoid absolute paths in build scripts. Groovy only performs String interpolation for double-quoted strings (`"$buildDir/test-results"`). If you have the `jacoco` and `java` plugins applied, all the Sonar properties shown in your snippet should be preconfigured correctly.

Comment: I tried that - please see update. Question: Does spaces in folder names cause a problem

Comment: You need to run `gradle test sonarRunner`. The `sonarRunner` plugin must be applied to the root project only, not to subprojects (as explained in the SonarRunner plugin chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)). You can also try with your manual `sonarRunner` configuration, but you'll need to fix `'$buildDir/test-results'` (needs double quotes) and should replace the absolute path with `project.file("relative/path")`. I doubt that spaces will cause problems, but you can always try to rename the affected folders.

Comment: Thank you. This seems very relevant "The sonarRunner plugin must be applied to the root project only, not to subprojects (as explained in the SonarRunner plugin chapter in the Gradle User Guide)" I will try this out and revert